# Is it possible to create custom HTML elements that act like standard ones

Tags: javascript, html

How do i go about creating a custom HTML element that acts like a link
with out using inline Javascript

For example:

```
<x-button href="...">...<x-button>
```

Is it possible to create an element like `<x-button>` that will take an attribute such as `href` the same way an `a` element would?

Comment: So what is your question exactly? How to make a link? Could you be more clear about the problem?

Comment: This is far too broad for SO's format. For the first, look into [web components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components). For the second, you'd just use a `click` event handler to set the `location` to the destination URL (but beware that unless you do a lot of styling on that button, that would be a surprising user experience -- use links for links, buttons for actions).

Comment: "I had an idea" isn't a question.  Have you attempted to *implement* your idea?  Is something not working?  What were you expecting to happen?  Why?

Comment: You can find your question's answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link).

Comment: The question is quite clear, no need for overthinking, I want to add an attribute to an HTML element, whether it is a custom element or a standard element.

Comment: @Vlad: Ok, then add one.  Observe: https://jsfiddle.net/rh1hyyrj/  What's stopping you from doing this?  What happens when you *try*?

Comment: @David: https://jsfiddle.net/zv5zmsqr/2/

Comment: @Vlad: Your custom element successfully displays in that example.  What's the problem?

Comment: @David: It does not display as a link, its displayed just as an unknown element, i want to achieve the same behavior as a <a> element for my custom element

Comment: @Vlad: It does not display as a link because it's not a link.  You'd need to write your custom behavior through a combination of JavaScript and CSS.  For example, you can style that element to have a different color, an underline, and a different mouse cursor on hover so as to mimic the appearance of a link.  And you can respond to its click event in JavaScript and perform a redirect to as to mimic the behavior of a link.  But no browser existing browser is going to support custom behavior that you're making up right now.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML element don't support every attribute. If you want a button acting like a link, you can use directly the `<a href="#"></a>` element and add some css on it too look like a button.

Comment: Yes but that's exactly what I don't want. I want to add that attribute to a custom element that will act as a link.

Comment: Well you can also direcly wrap it like:<a href="#"><button type="button">Text of Some Page</button></a> or a ink looks like a button https://jsfiddle.net/v6nnapvb/1/

Comment: Well, again... this beats my whole idea of a custom element. I don't want to use existing methods, I want to create a custom HTML element with a href attribute, or if possible, extend an existing one to include this attribute.

Comment: I don't really get it. You want to create a custom HTML element ? And what do you want to do ?

Comment: A custom element doesn't exactly act like a link, it acts more like a div, just a container with no real purpose, adding a href="..." won't do anything, but I know that its possible somehow to add that attribute in the elements API I suppose, Or is it?